# Can I use a noun clause introduced by "that" as the direct object of "curse"?

Tags: nouns, transitive-verbs

I wrote the following sentence "She cursed that only leaving could cure her." I am aware it sounds odd; I am purely interested in whether it is grammatical. I was told that it is not because "curse" is transitive and requires a direct object.

I believe it is grammatical because Merriam Webster says that "that" can be "used as a function word to introduce a noun clause that is usually the subject or object of a verb or a predicate nominative." For this sense, they provide the example, "[She] said that he was afraid." I feel that my usage is not meaningfully different from the example. They both follow the form transitive verb + noun clause introduced by "that". I believe that "curse" does have a direct object (the noun clause), satisfying the requirements of a transitive verb.

Is there a reason "says" can have its direct object be a noun clause while "curse" cannot? Is there something invalid about my noun clause?

Thanks!

Comment: But the sentence *provides* a transitive object of the ***utterance*** ([Merriam-Webster, verb, sense 2 b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curse#h2)): "that only leaving could cure her."

Comment: @JasonBassford yes, I agree. I was just wondering if there is any merit to the criticism I received that called this sentence ungrammatical.

Comment: On the grammatical basis of there being no direct object? No. It's indirect speech. (Which sounds odd, if you put the two things together …)

Comment: Only some verbs can be used as quotative verbs. And only some verbs can be used as reporting verbs (She said / replied / hinted ... that ... ; He asked / enquired ... whether ...). 'Curse' is used when appropriate as a quotative verb, but not as a reporting verb. Different verbs behave differently –  probably the prime tenet of English grammar.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you. Is my particular example a valid usage of curse as a quotative verb?

Comment: Your particular answer wrongly uses 'curse' as if it were a reporting verb. You'd need something like ' "Drop dead!" he cursed under his breath.' Perhaps you're aiming for 'She cursed that only leaving could cure her.' This is not a reporting usage, but really a shortened form of the transitive usage 'She cursed the fact that only leaving could cure her.'  Compare 'She regretted the fact that only leaving could cure her'  and 'She regretted that only leaving could cure her.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth sorry to bother you, but I am still confused by your answer. You said "Perhaps you're aiming for 'She cursed that only leaving could cure her.'" I am confused by this because it isn't what I'm aiming for; it is what I originally said verbatim. Is a shortened usage like this acceptable? Frankly, saying "the fact that" is really grating on me; it is a waste of words that adds no clarity.

Comment: No, "curse" is definitely intransitive in your example, since it has no direct object ( it would be transitive in, e.g. "Ed cursed his bad luck"). The declarative content clause "that only leaving could cure her" is not an object but complement of the verb "cursed". "That" is a subordinator introducing the content clause (aka _that_ clause). Importantly, objects are always noun phrases, never clauses. Btw, please don't call it a 'noun clause'. Terms like that are best reserved for elementary school grammar books.

Comment: Different grey-area constructions will grate on the ears of different people. I find "She cursed that only leaving could cure her." a particularly grating sentence. DW256 has found some examples on the internet that delete 'the fact that'.  It may be becoming an accepted usage; it's always a contentious area when this occurs (and English is a living, evolving language). I'd wager that a usage panel would find it about 40% acceptable (or 40% grammatical, if you prefer the term) at the moment. As opposed to 100% for 'accepted that' and 'swore that', and perhaps <10% for 'praised that'.

Comment: @BillJ are you saying that Merriam Webster is inaccurate, then? Under its definition of "that," it says "...used as a function word to introduce a noun clause that is usually the subject or object of a verb or a predicate nominative" (Entry 2, Sense 2b). It explicitly says that the noun clause not only _can_ be used as an object but _frequently_ is. Would you also argue that "say" is intransitive whenever you use the construction "say that..."? I don't think that is accurate.

Comment: Yes, I am. The term 'function word' is sometimes used for words that  have no real meaning. But it's a very general term; something more specific is required. The term 'subordinator' is more specific since it refers to words like "that" which introduce subordinate clauses. And 'subordinator' (or subordinating conjunction in trad grammar) is, of course, a genuine POS, like noun, verb, adverb etc. Re your last question, yes: in, for e.g "He said that he was ill, "that he was ill" is a declarative content clause functioning as **complement** (not object) of "said"; thus "say" is intransitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem to be an established use of *curse*

> ...both of us cursing that we had not brought our skis
>
> ...and cursed that he hadn't the time to bind it before now
>
> ...others curse that they never got within range

All of the above make sense if the definition of *curse* is taken to be ([Merriam Webster 2b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curse)):

> to execrate in fervent and often profane terms

Used by news outlets:

[Take the neighbor who, unknown to me, cleared the snow off my car the other morning so that when I went outside, running late, cursing that I hadn’t left time to brush and scrape, I was surprised by a car that was already snow-free and ready to go.](https://www.chicagotribune.com/columns/mary-schmich/ct-met-snow-storm-angel-mary-schmich-20180208-story.html)

[I distinctly recall everyone passing the four-mile mark, checking their watches and cursing that they're running too quickly.](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/othersports/athletics/london-marathon/11539434/The-11-awesome-and-awful-stages-of-the-London-Marathon.html)

[Beneath the streets, where the sun isn’t shining, sweaty and sultry MBTA riders have been bemoaning the transportation agency, cursing that they don’t do enough to keep passengers cooled-off while waiting to catch a ride to or from work during their commute](https://www.bostonmagazine.com/news/2013/07/17/despite-what-you-think-its-hotter-outside-than-riding-on-the-mbta/)

[Sisters Rosie Clarke, 23, Emma Clarke, 25, and Lowri Clarke, 17, are set for a weekend of family fun - but they'll be cursing that they forgot to pack their wellies](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3137192/Raincoats-ready-100-000-hippies-hangers-music-fans-descend-Glastonbury-bag-best-spots-tents.html)

[He said during the ordeal he was cursing that he was so unlucky, but afterwards decided he was in fact very lucky to still be here.](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-04-14/solo-sailor-limps-way-to-port-lincoln-after-bight-storm/11000862)

[I spoke to him this morning and he was still cursing that he could not reach him.](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/5879694/crystal-palace-simon-jordan-dad-gun-127k-watch/)

In books:

I snapped one of the books shut, cursing that I hadn't thought to look and see what page I was up to.  ([Because of Her, KE Payne](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=agaTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT17&dq=%22cursing%20that%20I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL7pbartDpAhUHBogKHQ0UBvcQ6AEITTAE#v=onepage&q=%22cursing%20that%20I%22&f=false))

Sighing, and inwardly cursing that I had not gone home earlier, I made my way to the desk. ([Murder Mile, Mike Mulloy](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=U9yy5hZ08nQC&pg=PT64&dq=%22cursing%20that%20I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL7pbartDpAhUHBogKHQ0UBvcQ6AEIRDAD#v=onepage&q=%22cursing%20that%20I%22&f=false))

silently cursing that I hadn't successfully maneuvered an end to our chat. ([Animal Camp: Lessons in Love and Hope from Rescued Farm Animals, Kathy Stevens](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=di-cr98jUtoC&pg=PA163&dq=%22cursing%20that%20I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL7pbartDpAhUHBogKHQ0UBvcQ6AEIVjAF#v=onepage&q=%22cursing%20that%20I%22&f=false))

I followed, cursing that I had not chosen to wear my boots that morning [(When The Hills Ask For Your Blood: A Personal Story of Genocide and Rwanda, David Belton)](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=V7cpAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA223&dq=%22cursing%20that%20I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL7pbartDpAhUHBogKHQ0UBvcQ6AEIaDAH#v=onepage&q=%22cursing%20that%20I%22&f=false)

Comment: This is infelicitous. 'He execrated in fervent [and profane] terms that we had not brought our skis' is ungrammatical. It would be advisable to show exact examples from a reliable source. You need to give attributed links to your three examples. Yes, there are examples of the deleted form on the internet, but not that many when you get past the first page of  a Google search for "he cursed that he" for example, and fewer looking to be from acceptable sources (eg 'He couldn't even make out the other side, and there was no noisy detectable. He cursed that he didn't have a radio on him, ')